# App engine: transitioning from DB to NDB and having an issue with iterating through in Query objects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to iterate through a query, and my code was setup for DB. Now that I'm using NDB, I'm confused with the syntax. Basically in this code I'm trying to build an Index for the Search API. My database is large (~30000 entities), and each entity will become a document. I thought the best way to do this was just split up the job using task queues.

Anyway here is the code:

```
    q = Database.query()
    q.filter(Database.title > None)
    numEntities = q.count(limit=50000)
    logging.info(num)
    counter = 0 
    batchsize = 999

    while (counter<numEntities):
        logging.info(counter)
        if (counter == 0):
            resultsFetched = 0
            for p in q:
                resultsFetched+=1
                counter += 1
                if p.identifier:
                    # add code to call worker here
                    taskqueue.add(queue_name='buildSearchIndexWorker',target='buildsearch',url='/tasks/buildSearchIndexWorker',params={'ID':p.identifier})

                    if (resultsFetched == batchsize):
                        a, startCursor, more = q.fetch_page(999)
                        break
        else: 
            q.fetch_page(999,start_cursor = startCursor)
            resultsFetched = 0
            for p in q:
                resultsFetched+=1
                counter += 1
                if p.identifier:
                    # add code to call worker here
                    taskqueue.add(queue_name='buildSearchIndexWorker',target='buildsearch',url='/tasks/buildSearchIndexWorker',params={'ID':p.identifier})

                    if (resultsFetched == batchsize):
                        a, startCursor, more = q.fetch_page(999)
                        break
```

Basically from when I was using DB, there was an upper limit of I think 999 pulls per query. Does this limit still apply to NDB queries as well? If so, I want the code to do 999 pulls at a time, create a task queue, and then through using cursors, pull the next 999 entities. Is the way I wrote the code an appropriate way to iterate through the query object? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments about your existing code:

Running `q.count()` is best avoided. When attempting to iterate over large queries, there is no certainty that you'll be able to complete an entire iteration before the task times out. Secondly, `q.count()`, last I checked, is limited to a count of 1,000 entities.

The simple way I would tackle this problem is (consider this psuedo code, mostly):

```py
def _iterate_and_index(cursor=None):
    query = MyModel.query(keys_only=True)  # you need to reconstruct your query every time
    results, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(BATCH_SIZE or 999, start_cursor=cursor)

    # Immediately fire this task to continue this query.
    if more:
        deferred.defer(_iterate_and_index, cursor)

    queue = taskqueue.Queue('buildSearchIndexWorker')
    tasks_to_add = []

    for entity_key in results:
        task = taskqueue.Task(target='buildsearch', 
            url='/tasks/buildSearchIndexWorker',
            params={'entity_key':entity_key.urlsafe()})
        tasks_to_add.append(task)

    # Add tasks to queue, 100 at a time (100 is the API limit)
    while tasks_to_add:
        queue.add(tasks_to_add[:100])
        tasks_to_add = tasks_to_add[100:]
```

Some things to be aware of:

- If the runtime is terminated before all the tasks are added, the task will run again. Use tasknames to create idempotence if it is important that a single entity isn't indexed twice.
- I'm adding tasks to the queue in batches of 100 to reduce API calls. 100 is an API limit.
- Instead of passing `.identifier` to the tasks, I've chosen to make the query use `keys_only` to make the query more efficient - since you don't need any data about the entity during the actual query. This will save you time and money.
- Using `more` of `fetch_page` will remove your need to use `q.count()`.
- I `deferred.defer` the next iteration before actually processing the batch. This keeps things moving in parallel and speeds up the whole operation. It also prevents your cursors from becoming stale.

Learn more about the [deferred library here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred).

I would recommend taking a look at [this simple Mapper](http://blog.altlimit.com/2013/05/simple-mapper-class-for-ndb-on-app.html) library which uses deferred tasks (aka taskqueue) to solve large batch iterations and allows you to solve similar problems with an easy to implement pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, Josh -- it's very helpful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You problem with the query construction is you haven't read the docs on ndb queries and are assuming multi step construction is the same as db.

```
q = Database.query()
q.filter(Database.title > None)
numEntities = q.count(limit=50000)
```

With ndb each call to query or filter creates a new query object rather than adding to the existing query.  You code should be

```
q = Database.query()
q = q.filter(Database.title > None)
numEntities = q.count(limit=50000)
```

Some other point's

1. if you must do a count do a keys_only query.
2. I don't really see why you perform a count. I would run the query in a task and just monitor how much time has been consumed, then when you reach the 9 minute mark, start a new task where starting from where you have got up to.
3. there are still limits on fetch_page etc...

Ohh well I will stop there the other answer just appeared and covered the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it -- I gotta dig through the ndb docs more.